# IOS 16.2/ Appium 1.22.3-4 - Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID error

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcode14

Not able to launch application on simulators via appium 2.

```
Appium version installed: 1.22.3-4
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: macOS Monterey v12.6.3
Mobile platform/version under test: 16.2
Xcode: 14.2
Real device or emulator/simulator: Simulator - iPhone 14 Pro
Launch via IntelliJ with desired capabilities
Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
"platformName": "ios",
"appium:takesScreenshot": true,
"appium:automationName": "XCuiTest",
"appium:bundleId": "testProject",
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14 Pro",
"appium:fullReset": false,
"appium:language": "fr",
"appium:nativeWebTap": true,
"appium:newCommandTimeout": "12000",
"appium:noReset": true,
"appium:platformVersion": "16.2",
"appium:preventWDAAttachments": true,
"appium:udid": "F59DBC6F-2944-4D4B-B19A-903272B62DD3"
},
```

Getting below error

```
**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'F59DBC6F-2944-4D4B-B19A-903272B62DD3'**
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'mac26704.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14e3:9bb6:4f21:7ce8%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'F59DBC6F-2944-4D4B-B19A-903272B62DD3'
at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'mac26704.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14e3:9bb6:4f21:7ce8%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
```

Upgraded from Appium 1 to Appium 2. Tried other simulators like iPhone 13, iPhone 14, not working.

Comment: I find stack**overflow** questions to work best when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom.